# Delete columns where all values are 0

Tags: r

I have a numeric matrix with `15000` columns. I want to completely remove the columns where *all* values are `0`.

```
     col1     col2     col3     col4
row1  1        0        0        1
row2  3.4      0        0        2.4
row3  0.56     0        0        0
row4  0        0        0        0
```

Here I want to delete columns `col2` and `col3`, and keep the rest.
How can I do it with R?
Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How about this, using `apply` and `all`:

```
M <- as.matrix(data.frame(a=runif(10),b=rep(0,10),c=runif(10),d=rep(0,10)))

M[,which(!apply(M,2,FUN = function(x){all(x == 0)}))]
```

Comment: You can squeeze this down a little bit: `M[,which(!apply(M==0,2,all))]`

Comment: Or even further:  `M[ , !apply(M==0,2,all)]`

Comment: Slick. If there were no zeros in the data, you could swap zeros for NA, transpose the matrix, apply `complete.cases` and transpose back. Just putting it out there...

Answer (score 23):

A quicker way to do the same (3 - 5x faster) would be

```
M[,colSums(M^2) !=0]
```

EDIT: Added timing details of various approaches suggested here. The approach suggested by @Dwin using `M[, colSums(abs(M)) ! == 0]` seems to work fastest, especially when the matrix is large. I will update the benchmarking report if other solutions are suggested.

```
m <- cbind(rnorm(1000),0)
M <- matrix(rep(m,7500), ncol=15000)

f_joran   = function(M) M[, !apply(M==0,2,all)]
f_ramnath = function(M) M[, colSums(M^2) != 0]
f_ben     = function(M) M[, colSums(M==0) != ncol(M)]
f_dwin    = function(M) M[, colSums(abs(M)) != 0]

library(rbenchmark)
benchmark(f_joran(M), f_ramnath(M), f_ben(M), f_dwin(M), 
   columns = c('test', 'elapsed', 'relative'), 
   order = 'relative', replications = 10)


          test elapsed relative
4    f_dwin(M)  11.699 1.000000
2 f_ramnath(M)  12.056 1.030515
1   f_joran(M)  26.453 2.261133
3     f_ben(M)  28.981 2.477220
```

Comment: @Ramnath: It might be faster than squaring to use `abs()`

Comment: @Dwin. you were right. `abs()` indeed seems to work faster than squaring the matrix. See my answer for the timings.

Comment: Heh, Thanks for the timings. I would have concluded that I was wrong. A 3% difference is not worth the trouble.

Comment: For robustness, I would add ```drop=F```, e.g. ```f_dwin = function(M) M[, colSums(abs(M)) != 0, drop = F]```

Answer (score 3):

You mention 15,000 columns but not the number of rows.  If there are several thousand rows and speed is a concern, `colSums` will be quite a bit faster than `apply`.

```
m <- cbind(rnorm(1000),0)
M <- matrix(rep(m,7500), ncol=15000)
system.time(foo <- M[,which(!apply(M==0,2,all))])
#   user  system elapsed 
#   1.63    0.23    1.86 
system.time(bar <- M[,colSums(M)!=0])
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.340   0.060   0.413
identical(foo,bar)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: the issue with using `colSums(M) != 0` is that there could be negative values in the matrix.

Comment: Ah, true; and I didn't see your answer.  I started posting mine, got interrupted, and finished it 30 minutes later.