# Remove columns with zero values from a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data.frame:

```
SelectVar
     a   b  c   d   e   f   g   h   i j k l ll m n o p  q   r
1 Dxa8 Dxa8 0 Dxa8 Dxa8 0 Dxa8 Dxa8 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 0 Dxc8 0
2 Dxb8 Dxc8 0 Dxe8 Dxi8 0 tneg tpos 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 0 Dxi8 0
```

I would like to remove the columns with zero values in both rows from the data frame, so it yields a data frame as below:

```
SelectVar
     a   b    d    e    g   h     q   
1 Dxa8 Dxa8 Dxa8 Dxa8 Dxa8 Dxa8  Dxc8 
2 Dxb8 Dxc8 Dxe8 Dxi8 tneg tpos  Dxi8
```

Have tried:

```
SelectVar!=0
```

which yields a True/False dataframe, and:

```
SelectVar[, colSums(abs(SelectVar)) ! == 0]
```

which yields an error.

How could I remove the columns with zero values in each row?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You almost have it.  Put those two together:

```
 SelectVar[, colSums(SelectVar != 0) > 0]
```

This works because the factor columns are evaluated as numerics that are >= 1.

Comment: No, it does not work with `NA` values.  If `NA` value are present, replace the test with `!is.na(colSums(SelectVar != 0)) & colSums(SelectVar != 0) > 0` (or equivalent).

Comment: With `NA` just try: `SelectVar[, colSums(SelectVar != 0, na.rm = TRUE) > 0]`

Comment: @MatthewLundberg - Will this `SelectVar[, colSums(SelectVar == 0) == 0]` remove all columns with sum as zero?

Comment: @ChetanArvindPatil No.  The sum is taken over the expression `SelectVar == 0`, a logical, and gives the number of zero values.  That expression selects (not removes) all columns with no zero values.  To remove all columns that sum as zero: `SelectVar[, colSums(selectVar) != 0]`

Comment: @MatthewLundberg - Ok. What about this `SelectVar <- SelectVar [, colSums(SelectVar == 0) != nrow(SelectVar )]`?

Comment: @ChetanArvindPatil Looks like that removes a column if it contains any `0` value.

Comment: @M.Mashaye That will return identical results in all cases.  `abs(x) == 0` is equivalent to `x == 0`.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg what package does SelectVar come with, I've tried googling it but all I can find is info under the kimod package, is this correct?

Comment: @TheGoat That's the name of the `data.frame` in the question.

Comment: i'm worried that about negative values in the column, probably an absolute value is needed there; or shoot what if the col just happens to sum to exactly 0 with eq value pos and negative

Comment: @tofutim There's not a problem there.  `colSums` is taken over the logical `SelectVar != 0` so it is the count of nonzero elements.  It is not the sum of the column values.

Comment: Hey, is it possible to the get the names of the columns which will be deleted? For example in this case, "i" "j" "k" "ll" "m" "n" "o" "p"?

Answer (score 11):

A dplyr friendly solution:

`SelectVar %>% select_if(colSums(.) != 0)`

Comment: but what if there are negative values and negatives and positivea add up to 0? you would be removing those columns with this method, right?

Comment: Good catch @charlesdarwin! Most likely, yes. Though I've recently found another dplyr/tidyverse friendly solution ```purrr::discard(~all(is.na(.))) ```

Answer (score 10):

One option since `dplyr 1.0.0` could be:

```
df %>%
 select(where(~ any(. != 0)))

     a    b    d    e    g    h    q
1 Dxa8 Dxa8 Dxa8 Dxa8 Dxa8 Dxa8 Dxc8
2 Dxb8 Dxc8 Dxe8 Dxi8 tneg tpos Dxi8
```

Answer (score 6):

The faster option, by about 40% according to mean execution times, is

`df[,-(which(colSums(df)==0))]`

We can benchmark the two options with a simple example data frame consisting of 3,000 columns and two observations.

```
# Create simple 2 X 3000 data frame with many 1s and 0s
# 500 columns have all 0s
df = matrix(c(rep(c(0,1,1),1000),rep(c(1,0,0),1000)),nrow=2)
df = as.data.frame(df)

# Benchmark the two options in milliseconds, 100 times
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  df[,colSums(df != 0) > 0],
  df[,-(which(colSums(df)==0))]
  )

Unit: milliseconds
                             expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
       df[, colSums(df != 0) > 0] 23.3844 24.77905 30.24852 26.37730 29.17175 140.6486   100
 df[, -(which(colSums(df) == 0))] 17.3664 19.12815 21.58901 20.59055 22.29905  41.9485   100
```

Answer (score 5):

Try also

```
SelectVar[, !apply(SelectVar == 0, 2, all)]
```

This was taken from here:

[Delete all columns with 0 from matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6632018/delete-all-columns-with-0-from-matrix)

Comment: This is likely to be slower though, particularly on larger datasets. Also, I *think* the OP is looking for `any` not `all`.

Comment: Maybe, i just copy paste the post. It seems to work ok.

Answer (score 1):

All above answers are valid - 
but for some of us, perhaps the most intuitive solution to read following the goal `remove columns with zero values` is:

```
df %>% select(where(~ sum(.) != 0))
```

You can read it as: 
`For every column (~), remove it (!=) if its sum (sum(.)) is zero`

Answer (score 1):

simple answer that remove columns with any zeros:

```
columns_to_keep = (colSums(SelectVar != 0) == nrow(SelectVar))
NewTable = SelectVar[, columns_to_keep]
```

Comment: Do you mean `SelectVar[, columns_to_keep]`? And to be technically correct, you might use `colSums(SelectVar != 0)`, using `!=` instead of `>` in case there are negative numbers.

Comment: I corrected the answer, thank you!

Comment: I think it's done now, sorry I'm a new user.

Answer (score 0):

To remove any and all columns that contain only zeros, simply pass your data frame into the following function:

```
remove_zero_cols <- function(df) {
  rem_vec <- NULL
  for(i in 1:ncol(df)){
    this_sum <- summary(df[,i])
    zero_test <- length(which(this_sum == 0))
    if(zero_test == 6) {
      rem_vec[i] <- names(df)[i]
    }
  }
  features_to_remove <- rem_vec[!is.na(rem_vec)]
  rem_ind <- which(names(df) %in% features_to_remove)
  df <- df[,-rem_ind]
  return(df)
}
```

Example:

```
iris$Sepal.Width <- 0
new_df <- remove_zero_cols(iris)
print(new_df)
```

Comment: What is 6 in if(zero_test == 6)

Comment: The summary function on line 4 gives a 6 number summary of a column. If all 6 values are 0 then the column contains all zeros, and is thus removed.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like

```
   [row, column] = SelectVar.shape
    for j in range(column):
       if np.all(SelectVar.iloc[:, j] == 0):
           SelectVar = SelectVar.drop(SelectVar.columns[j], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but one other base R approach which can work here would be to assert that either the minimum or maximum value in each column is *not* zero:

```
colMax <- sapply(SelectVar, max, na.rm=TRUE)
colMin <- sapply(SelectVar, min, na.rm=TRUE)
SelectVar[, colMin != 0 | colMax != 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SelectVar <- data.frame(
  a = c("Dxa8", "Dxb8"),
  b = c("Dxa8", "Dxc8"),
  c = c(0, 0),
  d = c("Dxa8", "Dxe8"),
  e = c("Dxa8", "Dxi8"),
  f = c(0, 0),
  g = c("Dxa8","tneg"),
  h = c("Dxa8", "tpos"),
  i = c(0, 0),
  j = c(0, 0),
  k = c(0, 0),
  l = c(0, 0),
  ll = c(0, 0),
  m = c(0, 0),
  n = c(0, 0),
  o = c(0, 0),
  p = c(0, 0),
  q = c("Dxc8", "Dxi8"),
  r = c(0, 0)
)


print(SelectVar)
colSums(SelectVar == 0) == nrow(SelectVar)
    a     b     c     d     e     f     g     h     i     j     k     l    ll     m     n     o     p     q 
FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE 
    r 
 TRUE 
SelectVar[, colSums(SelectVar == 0) != nrow(SelectVar), drop=TRUE]
```

output is

```
a    b    d    e    g    h    q
1 Dxa8 Dxa8 Dxa8 Dxa8 Dxa8 Dxa8 Dxc8
2 Dxb8 Dxc8 Dxe8 Dxi8 tneg tpos Dxi8
```

or

```
# Identify columns with only zeros
zero_columns <- sapply(SelectVar, function(col) all(col == 0))

# Keep columns without only zeros
result <- SelectVar[, !zero_columns]
print(result)
```

or using library purr

```
library(purrr)
# Keep columns without only zeros
SelectVar %>%
  keep(~ any(. != 0))
print(result)
```