# Remove 0 columns from a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I see this question has been asked before but the solutions provided by them gives some strange results in my case.

my data frame`(df)` is this

```
         Department1  Department2  Department3  Cafeteria  Lobby(TT)  Lobby(Music Band)
  James  0            1            0            0          0          0
  Flynn  0            1            0            0          0          0
  Liam   0            1            0            0          0          0
```

My desired result is

```
       Department2  
James  1           
Flynn  1           
Liam   1
```

My code used to remove zero columns is

```
df <- df[, colSums(df != 0) > 0]
```

Above code was taken by this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21530306/7857035

The result  get is

```
1  1
2  1
3  1
```

Above code works when there are more than one column which contains different values other than zeros. How to get the desired result in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate fix to your problem is to use `drop=FALSE` when subsetting the data frame:

```
df <- df[, colSums(df != 0) > 0, drop=FALSE]
```

This will tell R not to coerce the data frame down to the lowest dimension, which in this case is a numeric vector.  As you seem to have already noticed, coercion would not be a problem if you have more than one non zero sum column.

### Demo

Comment: I deleted it because a true `colSums(df) == 0` does not necessarily mean the column contains all zeros.  I guess `df[colSums(df == 0) == 0]` would be better.

Comment: @RichScriven Right...but I think it would be OK if the OP has the constraint that all numbers are positive.  Then, the only way that a column could have a sum of zero would be if every number were zero.

Answer (score 2):

I'm getting accustomed to using `purrr::keep` for similar tasks to this.

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df <- read.table(text = "
name   Department1  Department2  Department3  Cafeteria  lobby_TT   lobby_music
James  0            1            0            0          0          0
Flynn  0            1            0            0          0          0
Liam   0            1            0            0          0          0",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactor = FALSE)

df %>%
  column_to_rownames("name") %>%
  keep(~all(.x) != 0)

#       Department2
# James           1
# Flynn           1
# Liam            1
```