# R remove columns from data.table that sum to 0 - still not working

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

This may seem like a duplicate question but maybe I am missing something here.

I have been trying to remove just the columns where the sum of absolute values add to zero from a data.table.

I searched and found many solutions on this site that claim to work, and in fact, when I copy/paste exact code, it does work. However, for some reason, I can not duplicate it with my data.table.

The result of almost anything I do turns my data.table into a list. I even tried to convert my data.table to data.frame to try these solutions with no luck.

from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530168/remove-columns-with-zero-values-from-a-dataframe):

```
SelectVar[, colSums(SelectVar != 0) > 0]
```

Does not work.

```
SelectVar[, !apply(SelectVar == 0, 2, all)]
```

Does not work either.

```
remove_zero_cols <- function(df) {
  rem_vec <- NULL
  for(i in 1:ncol(df)){
    this_sum <- summary(df[,i])
    zero_test <- length(which(this_sum == 0))
    if(zero_test == 6) {
      rem_vec[i] <- names(df)[i]
    }
  }
  features_to_remove <- rem_vec[!is.na(rem_vec)]
  rem_ind <- which(names(df) %in% features_to_remove)
  df <- df[,-rem_ind]
  return(df)
}
```

This function also does not work.

I checked the class of each parameter and they are all either numeric or integer types. I also checked for any NA's and found none.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I've been avoiding iterating manually with a for loop checking one column at a time - perhaps that is the solution I need? I was trying to do this a little more elegantly if possible.

Comment: Question: If the sum of _absolute_ values is zero, then it means that every value in the column is also zero.  Is this what you intended to say?

Comment: Yes. I want to drop data.table columns that ONLY contain 0's all the way down each row.

Answer (score 3):

Add `with = FALSE` to the first solution you referenced to if you are working on a data.table.

```
# Create example data frame
SelectVar <- read.table(text = "    a   b  c   d   e   f   g   h   i j k l ll m n o p  q   r
1 Dxa8 Dxa8 0 Dxa8 Dxa8 0 Dxa8 Dxa8 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 0 Dxc8 0
2 Dxb8 Dxc8 0 Dxe8 Dxi8 0 tneg tpos 0 0 0 0  0 0 0 0 0 Dxi8 0",
                        header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Convert to a data.table
library(data.table)

setDT(SelectVar)

SelectVar[, colSums(SelectVar != 0) > 0, with = FALSE]
#       a    b    d    e    g    h    q
# 1: Dxa8 Dxa8 Dxa8 Dxa8 Dxa8 Dxa8 Dxc8
# 2: Dxb8 Dxc8 Dxe8 Dxi8 tneg tpos Dxi8
```

Answer (score 2):

The OP has requested to *remove just the columns where the sum of absolute values add to zero*. Later on, he has clarified that he wants *to drop data.table columns that ONLY contain 0's all the way down each row*.

This can be achieved by using the `any()` function

```
library(data.table)

#create sample data
n_rows <- 10L
n_cols <-  5L
DT <- data.table(id = 1:n)
dat_cols <- sprintf("dat%i", seq.int(n_cols))
for (j in seq.int(n_cols)) set(DT, NULL, dat_cols[j], 0L)
set.seed(1L)
DT[sample.int(n_rows, 0.1 * n_rows), (sample.int(n_cols, 0.5 * n_cols)) := 1L]
DT
```

> ```
>     id dat1 dat2 dat3 dat4 dat5
>  1:  1    0    0    0    0    0
>  2:  2    0    1    1    0    0
>  3:  3    0    0    0    0    0
>  4:  4    0    0    0    0    0
>  5:  5    0    0    0    0    0
>  6:  6    0    0    0    0    0
>  7:  7    0    0    0    0    0
>  8:  8    0    0    0    0    0
>  9:  9    0    0    0    0    0
> 10: 10    0    0    0    0    0
> ```

```
# find columns which are all zero using any()
dat_cols <- sprintf("dat%i", seq.int(n_cols))
zero_cols <- setDT(DT)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) !any(x)), 
                .SDcols = dat_cols]
# remove columns in place
DT[, (names(which(unlist(zero_cols)))) := NULL][]
```

> ```
>     id dat2 dat3
>  1:  1    0    0
>  2:  2    1    1
>  3:  3    0    0
>  4:  4    0    0
>  5:  5    0    0
>  6:  6    0    0
>  7:  7    0    0
>  8:  8    0    0
>  9:  9    0    0
> 10: 10    0    0
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tidyverse solution. You could convert your data.table into a tibble and then go from there.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(a = 1:5, b = -1:3, c = 0)

selection_criteria <- (colSums(abs(df)) != 0)
df[selection_criteria]
```

Comment: Thank you for updating. I have removed my respective comments.

Answer (score 1):

Before:

```
library(tidy verse)
DT = as_tibble(list(x=c(1,0), y=c(0,0)))
DT

A tibble: 2 x 2
        x     y
      <dbl> <dbl>
  1     1     0
  2     0     0
```

Use:

```
DT1 = DT %>% select_if(any)
DT1
```

After:

```
  tibble: 2 x 1
        x
      <dbl>
  1     1
  2     0
```