# Create plot between two points representing confidence intervals in R

Tags: boxplot, confidence-interval, r-whisker

I have a data frame similar to the one created in the example below:

[Remove columns with zero values from a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530168/remove-columns-with-zero-values-from-a-dataframe/60015429#60015429)

Is it possible to create a whisker plot connecting these two points in R? I would want the variables on the x-axis and the points on the y-axis.