# Removing columns from dataframe that have value greater than -1

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm trying to remove columns where all the values present are greater than -1 (ex: -0.45 or 0.45). However, if there is at least one row with a value equal to or less than -1 (ex: -1.14) I want to keep these columns.

I've tried the following but get bag an error in the data table:

```
i evaluates to a logical vector length 17645 but there are 24 rows. Recycling of logical i is no longer allowed as it hides more bugs than is worth the rare convenience. Explicitly use rep(...,length=.N) if you really need to recycle.
```

Original DF (Example)

```
Cell    Gene1    Gene2      Gene3     Gene4      Gene5
Cell1   0.02    -1.100.2    0.002   -1.772.1    -0.0884
Cell2   0.19    -1.098.0    0.068   -1.837.0    0.0685
Cell3   0.13    -1.328.7    -1.580  -1.687.6    0.2554
Cell4   -0.032  -1.245.3    0.004   -1.528.4    -0.2037
```

Desired DF (Example)

```
Cell    Gene2       Gene3     Gene4   
Cell1   -1.100.2    0.002   -1.772.1    
Cell2   -1.098.0    0.068   -1.837.0    
Cell3   -1.328.7    -1.580  -1.687.6    
Cell4   -1.245.3    0.004   -1.528.4
```

Command to Filter Values

```
desired_df <- original_df[sapply(original_df, function(x) max(x) <= -1)]
```

Comment: Related, possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/21530168/680068

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `keep()` and `discard()` from `purrr` (which is in the tidyverse). You would use these in conjunction with `any()` and `all()`.

My example uses `mtcars`, but this would translate to any dataset.

```r
library(purrr)

# keep all columns with any value less than or equal to 10
mtcars %>% 
  keep(~ any(. <= 10))

# remove all columns with all values greater than 10
mtcars %>% 
  discard(~ all(. > 10))
```

You can make the function as advanced as you'd like. This will keep columns where a certain percentage of values meets a criteria.

```r
# keep all columns where 90% of the values are less than or equal to 10
mtcars %>% 
  keep(~ (sum(. <= 10) / length(.)) > 0.9)
```

Comment: would it be possible to drop columns by a certain percentage as well? like if more than 90% of the values with of -1 in a column?

Comment: I would also note this all works in a `select(where(...))` context as well. It is just however you want to go about it.

Comment: Thanks first of all, pretty nice and simple approach. I'm going to try and implement now :)

Comment: out of curiosity, how would this go about with the above solution, deleting columns where a certain percentage of values is missing?

Comment: Just use `discard()` instead of `keep()`! Same idea, just need to think through it to make sure you are getting exactly what you want.

Comment: yes, saw that they are basically the inverse depending on how you use your operators as well, thanks so much @Adam :D

Answer (score 1):

Next time try to put some reproducible data frame, but considering what you are looking for, the following should work:

```
library(dplyr)
desired_df <- original_df %>% select_if(~any(. <=-1 ))
```

Comment: The `*_if()` functions in `dplyr` have been superseded. I believe the current syntax would be `select(where(~ any(. <= -1)))`.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.