# R - Remove columns with 0 values in df with 1 or more remaining columns

Tags: r, loops

I am writing a piece of R code which is looping through a dataframe and then running time series predictions from the subsetted dataframe. However, the manner in which I created the loop gives me a number of columns with 0 values. There could a single column with non zero values or many columns with non zero values, but there will always be a minimum of one column with non zero values. Each iteration through the loop could yield a different number of non-zero columns.

Please see the following discussions regarding this topic.

[Remove columns with zero values from a dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530168/remove-columns-with-zero-values-from-a-dataframe)

[Delete all columns with 0 from matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6632018/delete-all-columns-with-0-from-matrix)

How do I get the following code to work? I will provide 2 examples that captures the crux of my issue. The first example works great and is exactly what I need to adapt to work.

```
dat <- data.frame(x = rep(0, 10), y = rnorm(10), z = rep(0, 10), a = rnorm(10)) 
dat <- dat[, colSums(dat) > 0]
```

The second example fails because there is only a single column of non zero values.

```
dat2 <- data.frame(x = rep(0, 10), y = rep(0, 10), z = rep(0, 10), a = rnorm(10))
dat2 <- dat2[, colSums(dat2) > 0]
```

Any insights would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with either `drop=FALSE` as the default is `drop=TRUE` or you remove the `,` and it will return a `data.frame`.  For more info, please check `?"["`

```
dat2[colSums(dat2) > 0]
```

Or

```
dat2[,colSums(dat2) > 0, drop=FALSE]
```

If you use `subset`, the default is `drop=FALSE`

```
subset(dat2, select=colSums(dat2) > 0)
```

Comment: (+1) Explanation: Data frames are just special lists, and `[j]` is "list syntax", which always returns a list. `[i, j, drop=FALSE]` is syntactic sugar that is equivalent to `[[j]][i]`. For the difference between `[[` and `[` on lists, see `help('[')` and `help('[.data.frame')`. Setting `drop=TRUE` prevents R from "dropping" down from a data frame to a single vector.

Comment: @akrun - That looks like it did the trick. I tested it on a smaller subset just now and will run through the whole procedure now with the full dataset. Ill let you know if I run into any more issues. Thanks again for the quick response.

Comment: @ssdecontrol Your explanation is really helpful for me to understand the reason behind the issue. Thank you for taking the time to explain that to me. I thought that the property of the df was fundamentally different than a list and couldn't see why the code wasn't working.